# fail to read csv file with quotations using fgetcsv()

Tags: php, csv, double-quotes, fgetcsv

I have a csv file that contains double quotes. when I read it using php fgetcsv(), the fields contain quotation will retrun null:

```
while(($data=fgetcsv($handle,5000,'|'))!==false){
    echo $data[0];
}
```

and the csv file may look like this

```
25" H x 8" W |15" H x 5" W
17.5" H x 9" W | 5" H x 12" W
```

Could anybody give me some advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) defaults to using a `"` as an enclosure character, but you can change this to another different character (e.g. a tilde `~`) that isn't used anywhere in your data; then the `"` won't be misinterpreted

```
while(($data=fgetcsv($handle,5000,'|','~'))!==false){
```

Comment: See, here comes the strange thing. I did what you just said but it didn't work. But if I remove all the white spaces after the quotes, it will be fine, even if I don't make changes like you said. I am totally confused.

Comment: I just figured out why. I use "Open Office" to make csv files, and it turns out that the software automatically convert white spaces into some random character. That's why it works ok when I removes the white spaces. Thank you for your reply, it makes sense.